# C# How to add an image on button array buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

How can I add an image on buttons of button array ?

```
Button[] mybuttons = new Button[] {Button1,Button2}; //My button array

mybuttons[1].image=new Bitmap("Click.jpg"); ///Gives Error
```

'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' does not contain a definition for 'Image' and no extension method 'Image' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

C# is case sensitive. Also, you need to use an [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) and give it an ImageUrl, not a [Button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx). The web control Button does not have an Image property.

Comment: But, I need to use button array that does not have imagebutton property.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you're out of luck, the Button Class only has an Image property when you're writing a Windows Forms Application. Windows Forms applications use this Button Class, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx. You cannot use the System.Windows.Forms.Button class in ASP.NET. In an ASP.NET web application the Button Class comes from System.Web.UI.WebControls and does not implement the Image property at all.